# ntp cannot open shared object file: Permission denied

Tags: permissions, libraries, dynamic-linking

On a server I haven't worked on, ntpd is broken:

```
# /etc/init.d/ntpd start
ntpd: error while loading shared libraries:
  libz.so.1: cannot open shared object file: Permission denied
```

but permissions look right:

```
# locate libz.so.1 | xargs ls -l
lrwxrwxrwx root root /usr/lib64/libz.so.1 -> libz.so.1.2.3
-rwxr-xr-x root root /usr/lib64/libz.so.1.2.3
lrwxrwxrwx root root /usr/lib/libz.so.1 -> libz.so.1.2.3
-rwxr-xr-x root root /usr/lib/libz.so.1.2.3
-rw-r--r-- root root /usr/lib/vmware-tools/lib32/libz.so.1/libz.so.1
-rw-r--r-- root root /usr/lib/vmware-tools/lib64/libz.so.1/libz.so.1
-rw-r--r-- root root /usr/lib/vmware-tools/lib32/libz.so.1
-rw-r--r-- root root /usr/lib/vmware-tools/lib64/libz.so.1
```

`LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is empty and the server is 64 bit:

```
# uname -a
Linux my.server 2.6.18-128.el5 #1 SMP [...] x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

*Update:*

```
# ldd /usr/sbin/ntpd
libz.so.1 => /usr/lib64/libz.so.1
```

and

```
# ls -l /usr/lib64/libz.so.1
lrwxrwxrwx root root /usr/lib64/libz.so.1 -> libz.so.1.2.3
# ls -l /usr/lib64/libz.so.1.2.3
-rwxr-xr-x root root /usr/lib64/libz.so.1.2.3
```

Comment: What does `ldd /usr/sbin/ntpd` give? Also, are you running SELinux or similar?

Comment: @derobert: I don't think it's a SELinux, but how to be sure? ldd looks right, I've updated the question.

Comment: Weird. What distribution is this exactly (some kind of RHEL5, but official or CentOS or other, and what version)? Please post the output of `strace /usr/sbin/ntpd`. If that doesn't fail, post the output of `bash -x /etc/init.d/ntpd start`.

Answer (score 2):

I have seen similar issue with one of my application and it was due to selinux in enforcing state. Change : /etc/selinux/config
from 
SELINUX=enforcing  ## or permissive
to 
SELINUX=disabled

This should fix it. 
http://sysadminupdates.com/blog/2015/05/11/so-cannot-open-shared-object-file-permission-denied/